# Verb "to be" in the Bilingual bible version

Tags: word-study, spanish

Some time ago, I was asking about the difference in John 4:20 about the verb "to be". I don't understand why in the Spanish version we read:  "en Jerusalén 'es' el lugar donde se debe adorar".

And not: en Jerusalén "está" el lugar donde ....

Give please one example describing the second one in English, "está".

How would it be then: en Jerusalén "está (to be)" el lugar, in English?

Answer (score 1):

If I were giving directions to the temple in Jerusalem I might say "el templo está en Jerusalén" (the temple is in Jerusalem).

If someone asked me "what is the place of worship?" I might respond that "Jerusalén es el lugar de adoración" (Jerusalem is the place of worship).

Both appear to be viable renderings of John 4:20, depending on what the intended emphasis is:

- If the emphasis is on where the place is located: estar
- If the emphasis is on what Jerusalem is (or what its temple is): ser

*to be sure, the succeeding verses indicate that Jerusalem *is not* the only appropriate place for worship.